# Extending Asp.net MVC 3 Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

I have a model that contains a property for an image url:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
public string Logo { get; set; }
```

As you can see the data type is an ImageUrl and I've usesd this fact to create an editor template in Views/Shared directory.

The template only needs to extened the default template by adding a few extra html elements. I'm not sure how to go about this.

I've tried specifying the template name when I call the html helpers but that doesn't seem to work for me.

The code I'm using is  (note that this is **inside** the custom template):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "string")
```

Incase you're wondering I got the template name by using reflector on the MVC 3 dll, then under

> System.Web.Mvc.Html

I looked at the contructor for the **TemplateHelpers** class and saw this line:

```
dictionary3.Add(typeof(string).Name, new Func<HtmlHelper, string>(DefaultEditorTemplates.StringTemplate));
```

Cheers for any Help
Tony

### Update

Forgot to mention. The reason I'm doing this is to take advantage of the unobtrusive validation that's with MVC 3

Comment: Why not just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)` instead of `EditorFor` in your editor template?

Comment: :-\ Brain fart. Post as answer and I'll accept

Comment: Hehe, it happens all the time to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)` instead of `EditorFor` in your editor template? :)